# Passing radio check box values into different lists depending on what the user selected

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view page that looks like this

```
@if (item.IHP != null)
{    
    @foreach (ItemHasParts ihp in item.IHP)
        {
            Part part = db.Parts.Find(ihp.PartID);
            string partID = part.ID.ToString();
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @part.PartIDLink
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelPart => part.MFG_number)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelPart => part.Name)
                </td>                         
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Harvest")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Transfer")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.RadioButton(partID, "Dispose")
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

As you can see, next to each part it generates 3 options(Harvest/Transfer/Dispose).
I will give an example of how I think this would best work.

Example//

Say there are 5 parts, then user decides to harvest 1 part, transfer 1 part, then dispose of the remaining 3 parts. It would be ideal if I could pass this to a list in the controller. (List of disposals/transfers/harvests). But I don't know how I could go about this, if that's even possible, or if there is a better way to do it possibly? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the code for the controller and your model please.

Comment: I think your code would not compiler because I see an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would doe I am using checkboxes you could modify my code and use radio buttons. However I think check boxes make more sense from my understanding of your context

In the model that you are using add a list of possible parts

```
public class YourModel
{
    //add this line to your model
    public List<Part> parts { get; set; }
}
```

Create the part model that should have a id name and a boolean to see if used

```
public class Part
{
    public int options_id { get; set; }
    public string option_name { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And finally on your razor page add this to generate the ui you can modify as you please but this is the most basic version

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.parts.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
            @Model.parts[i].option_name
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.parts[i].options_id)
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.parts[i].isSelected)
    </div>
}
```

If you have any question or if this does not answer your question don't hesitate to tell me. Hope this helps. :)